# Reading and summing columns from files

Tags: sum, fortran

I have 2 tables which contain 2 columns (id, value). All the tables have the same number of rows (id). So, I want to sum columns `value` from all the tables for each id.

Can anyone help me how I can do that with Fortran?
Please find below a part of the code that I wrote but in line 19, it does not estimate properly the summation.

```
integer :: id,idmax,nf,files,write_id
real, allocatable, dimension(:) :: val,vct_val,sum_files
idmax=5
nfiles=2
allocate (vct_val(idmax))
allocate(val(nfiles))
allocate (sum_files(idmax))
nf=0 !nf is the number of the file
do nf = 1,nfiles  
  open(10,file=fname_daily)    
   do id=1, idmax
    read(10,'(i6,1x,f16.2)') write_id,val(nf)
    vct_val(id)=val(nf)
 print *, 'read file ', write_id, vct_val(id), val(nf)
  end do !for all rows(id)
enddo !for all nfiles
do id=1, idmax
  print *, 'file1 sum', write_id, val(1)
  print *, 'file2 sum', write_id, val(2)
  sum_files(id)=val(1)+val(2)
end do !for all rows(id)

write(20,'(i6,A,f20.2)') (write_id, tab, sum_files(write_id),  write_id=1, idmax)
```

In the following you can find an example of file 1 and file 2 for which I want to sum their columns "value" for each id.
**file1**
"id"           "value"

```
 1        51000.00  
 2      1612000.00  
 3      1520000.00  
 4      1520000.00  
 5      1134000.00
```

**file2**
"id"      "value"

```
 1     35740000.00
 2     24460000.00
 3     21800000.00
 4     54280000.00
 5     42530000.00
```

The first print(line 14) gives the following correct values:

```
 read file            1   51000.0000       51000.0000    
 read file            2   1612000.00       1612000.00    
 read file            3   1520000.00       1520000.00    
 read file            4   1520000.00       1520000.00    
 read file            5   1134000.00       1134000.00    
 read file            1   35740000.0       35740000.0    
 read file            2   24460000.0       24460000.0    
 read file            3   21800000.0       21800000.0    
 read file            4   54280000.0       54280000.0    
 read file            5   42530000.0       42530000.0
```

However, the second print (line 18) gives only the values for id 5:

```
 file1 sum           5   1134000.00    
 file2 sum           5   42530000.0    
 file1 sum           5   1134000.00    
 file2 sum           5   42530000.0    
 file1 sum           5   1134000.00    
 file2 sum           5   42530000.0    
 file1 sum           5   1134000.00    
 file2 sum           5   42530000.0    
 file1 sum           5   1134000.00    
 file2 sum           5   42530000.0    
 file1 sum           5   1134000.00    
 file2 sum           5   42530000.0
```

Comment: By add you mean tu sum them? Or to append them somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I want to sum all the columns "values" from the different files for each row (id). By the way, If there is a way to append the columns first in one file (all the columns from the 3 files) then I could sum them.

Comment: OK, now I see your problem is not the `add` but reading the values from file. Your titel is pretty confusing when the question is actually about reading. How does your file look like? What does it mean " it does not read properly the values"? Are there any error messages? How do the error messages look like? Is the output wrong?

Comment: The files have, for example, the following format                                                   1            51000.00,
2        1612000.00,
3        1520000.00 etc
It does not return any error, but the output file writes properly the first column with all the rows (id=1 to 100) but the column "value" takes only the value zero (0.00). I think that the problem is the arrays val(nfiles) and vct_val(id).

Comment: Put a short example of the file into the question. And also the description of the problem. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the line `"id"      "value"` present inside the file? Or the line `file1`? It is not clear.

Comment: No, the files do not contain any of the two lines. They don't contain any character only the numbers.

Comment: Your summation is very strange `sum_files(ncell)=val(1)+val(2)` there is no dependence on `id` in it. Also, you should first verify that the files are read correctly before trying to add them.

Comment: Yes you are right, I corrected that. I also modified a bit the code and edited the question so you can find more details about the problem.

Comment: Crossposted to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/Za-2AzRJ-eA